# Location Unit Conversions Data

Tags: coordinates

I'm making a unit conversion code to convert from an Earth-Centered, Earth-Fixed (ECEF) location to a Latitude, Longitude, and Altitude (LLA) location and vice versa. I'm also making a code to convert from East, North, Up (ENU) to both of these locations as well. I have the code written out but I don't have any reliable data to test my code. Does anyone know of a link I can go to for the different location units of major cities and the north/south poles? If not a link to a reliable conversion calculator would help as well.

Answer (score 1):

I just found this page for matlab:
http://uk.mathworks.com/help/aeroblks/ecefpositiontolla.html 
I hope it can help.

Comment: Thanks this helps. Unfortunately though I still don't have any data to compare my ENU to ECEF conversion code to.